# Android iText Reading PDF: Difference between iText's Parser and Extraction

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I have tried examples from iText on Java and there is no difference in output.

This iText [Example1](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted1.java) is Parser of PDF but there is no difference with the extraction

This iText [Example2](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted2.java) is the Extractor of text from PDF.

What does iText PDF Parser do and what is the difference with iText Extraction?

I have tried both examples and there is no difference in output or I just have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the header of the code samples, you'll see a reference to the book where this is explained. I'm the author of the book, as well as the author of the examples. When you write a book, you usually don't throw people in the deep. You start with simple example, then you make them more complex, and finally you tell people about convenience methods.

Example2 uses the technology explained in Example1 under the hood.

What you have missed, is the context as explained in my book. Also: some of the examples published on SourceForge and on http://itextpdf.com/book/ are *bad examples*. They are there to explain how ***NOT*** to do something. Please don't copy/paste examples without reading the corresponding documentation!